# Is it possible to change numeric values to categorical values in a saved pickle file data frame and integrate it with XGBoost and Streamlit in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost, streamlit

Is it possible if we transform numerical value into categorical value after the dataframe become model/machine learning and saved as pickle format file ?

in this case i tried to create prediction system.

Figure below is the result of prediction afted i clicked button predict, and i wanted to transform the numerical value. as you can see in column fuel_type the value is 0 and is it possible transform it into categorical like "Petrol" and others

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPbFl.png)

If that possible, can anyone tell how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to change the column in your DataFrame to a string based on numeric values.

There are multiple possibilities one way is to use a dictionary and store the numeric values as keys with the corresponding string as an item. You can then change the elements in the column based on the dictionary. Below an example with 3 classes:

```
data = {'name' : [0, 1, 2],
        'year' : [2.010, 2.022, 2.022],
        'fuel_type' : [0, 1, 2],
        'km_driven' : [0, 0, 0],
        'transmission' : [1, 1, 1],
        'price' : [100, 100, 100]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


dict = {0: 'petrol', 1: 'diesel', 2:'electric'}
df['fuel_type'] = [dict[e] for e in df['fuel_type']]
```

This will return the following DataFrame:

```
   name   year fuel_type  km_driven  transmission  price
0     0  2.010    petrol          0             1    100
1     1  2.022    diesel          0             1    100
2     2  2.022  electric          0             1    100
```